# My Raspberry Pi 3 B Cant Connect To My New Wifi Router

Tags: pi-3, wifi, retropie

I Just got a new NETGEAR RAX80 Nighthawk Router and my Raspberry Pi 3 B (not plus) running retropie won't connect to my wifi.

I've tried:

- Making sure my SSID has no underscores.
- Connecting it to LAN And running an apt-get upgrade.
- Making sure its not on WPA/WPA2.

Is there any configs that could have messed up or something.
It worked on my previous router too. it's just when we got this new one.

EDIT: I'm using smart connect too (my router auto connects you to the 2.4 or 5GHz depending on the device.)

UPDATE: People said that it’s not a raspberry Pi problem. They are right. It’s an OS problem. It connects just fine on NOOBS And Raspbian Lite. Just not retropie

Comment: `Making sure its not on WPA/WPA2` - surely you WANT WPA/WPA2 ... have you perhaps enabled WPA3? I've read some devices that are not capable of WPA3 don't connect to a router that has both WPA2 and WPA3 enabled

Comment: If the RasPi was running on the previous router, then it's not a problem of the RasPi.

Comment: It’s set to WPA2